# Having a problem while getting the vendor folder for a symfony`project in Laravel Homestead environment

Tags: laravel, composer-php, symfony4, homestead

After I clone my symfony project to my workspace, I used `composer install` to get my project's `vendor` folder. I used Laravel Homestead as my working environment. Then it gives me below error.

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 89 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.0): Loading from cache
Plugin installation failed, rolling back
  - Removing ocramius/package-versions (1.4.0)

[RuntimeException]
  Could not delete /home/vagrant/code/oensys/project_test/server_side/vendor/ocramius/package-versions/src/PackageVersions:
```

Then I tried to the same thing after clear the cache (by using `rm -rf ~/.composer/cache` command) and delete the vendor folder which is created before, then it gives me the same error.

If anyone can help me with this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Please run `composer clearcache` first then run `composer install`.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada I did it. But it gives me the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Try running `composer install --no-plugins`

See https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1240 for other solutions.

Comment: Thanks @sarjon for the answer. What is the difference between `composer install --no-plugins` and `composer install` ? How is it effect to Symfony?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the issue follow the next steps:

```
composer install --no-plugins --no-scripts
composer install
```